# Is there a Bitcoin exchange that accepts paypal and no registration needed?

Tags: exchanges

I am looking for a Bitcoin exchange that allows me to input a wallet address and my paypal information and it will let me send *x* amount of btc to that address while paying with paypal in USD, RUB, EUR, etc.

Also, I don't want to create an account with the site and I want the site to be trusted.

Comment: Just curious: If you don't mind paying with paypal, why do you mind registering?

Comment: because I have an idea for something - 

Paypal will be needed, but I dont want the user having to spend time registering with some exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is economically impossible. Such an exchange doesn't exist or they are some sort of scams.

Paypal has very high fraud transaction rate due to high availability to obtain stolen PayPal credentials or stolen credit card numbers from darknet markets. Thus, exchanges allowing PayPal force strict Know-Your-Customer requirement on their users. It would be terrible, terrible, business decision to build such an exchange.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer and insight!

Comment: Why exactly would that be a bad business decision? How could it go wrong for the exchange?

Answer (score -1):

The answer above is completely false. I purchase Bitcoin through Coinvase all the time directly from my PayPal account.

What you need to do is make sure that your Paypal account is completely verified (by submitting whatever documents/info that they ask for)

Then, just sign up for the PayPal Debit Mastercard, which gets sent to you in the mail.

Once you have that, you can use it vurtually anywhere , and the funds will be deducted straight drom yiur paypal account.

THIS is when you open your CoinBase account, and choose "Add Credit/Debit Card" from the  " Payment Methods" menu, and enter the card details there.

Its very simple, and certainly worth doing if you want to avoid paying all the unneccesaty muddleman fees to places like Paxful, LocalBitcoins, or VirWox